# Recursively create a tree hierarchy off an array of strings

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, tree

I have an array of strings separated by "!". I am trying to break that string up and create a tree hierarchy recursively in my custom class called PivotGroup. For example, what I am aiming at is to break up string array

```
 string[] paths = new string[] {
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!15712",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!15722",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!13891"}
```

Into the PivotGroup class such as PivotGroup contains `ChildGroups[]` that embed the array strings.

So for example:

```
     PivotGroup pgGroup = new PivotGroup();
     pgGroup.ChildGroups[0] = PivotGroup[]; // Key:Book Level 3 Value: "AAA"
```

Now within Book Level 3 ChildGroups I need to set Book Level 4 which value is "EEE" and within the ChildGroups of "EEE" I would need to create another childGroup array which size in the case would be 3 called Book Level 5 and set another PivotGroup for each of following 15712, 15722, 13891

Here is my PivotGroup Class and embedded class Objects:

```
public class PivotGroup
{
    public PivotGroup() { }

    public PivotGroup(PivotGroupKey groupKey, PivotRow data, PivotGroup[] childGroups, bool leaf, int groupLevel)
    {
        GroupKey = groupKey;
        Data = data;
        ChildGroups = childGroups;
        Leaf = leaf;
        GroupLevel = groupLevel;
    }

    public PivotGroupKey GroupKey { get; private set; }
    public PivotRow Data { get; private set; }
    public PivotGroup[] ChildGroups { get; set; }
    public bool Leaf { get; private set; }
    public int GroupLevel { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GroupKey + ", GroupLevel: " + GroupLevel + ", Children: " +
            ChildGroups.Length + (Leaf ? " (Leaf)" : "");
    }
}

public class PivotGroupKey
{
    public PivotGroupKey()
    {
    }

    public PivotGroupKey(string keyGroup, string keyValue)
    {
        if(keyGroup != null)
            KeyGroup = string.Intern(keyGroup);

        if (keyValue != null)
            KeyValue = string.Intern(keyValue);
    }

    public string KeyGroup { get; private set; }
    public string KeyValue { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return KeyGroup + ": " + KeyValue;
    }
}

public class PivotRow
{
    public PivotRow()
    {
    }

    public PivotRow(string key, params object[] data) : this(key, true, data) { }

    public PivotRow(string key, bool entitled, params object[] data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Key = null;
        Entitled = entitled;
    }

    public object[] Data { get; private set; }
    public bool Entitled { get; private set; }
    public string Key { get { return null; } set { } }
}
```

Main program I tried:

```
public class BookLevels 
{
    public string Root { get; set; }
    public string BookLevel2 { get; set; }
    public string BookLevel3 { get; set; }
    public string BookLevel4 { get; set; }
    public string BookLevel5 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void BuildTree(string[] paths)
    {
        var BookPaths = paths.Select(x => x.Split('!'))
            .Select(x => new BookLevels
            {
                Root = x[0],
                BookLevel2 = x[1],
                BookLevel3 = x[2],
                BookLevel4 = x[3],
                BookLevel5 = x[4]
            }).GroupBy(z => new { z.BookLevel3, z.BookLevel4 }).ToArray();


        var BookLevel3Cnt = BookPaths.Select(q => q.Key.BookLevel3).Count();

        PivotGroup root = new PivotGroup(
            new PivotGroupKey("Total", ""),
            new PivotRow(null, new string[8]),
            new PivotGroup[BookLevel3Cnt], false, 0);

        foreach (var booklevel3 in BookPaths)
        {
            AddChildren(root, booklevel3);
        }
    }

    private static void AddChildren(PivotGroup root, IGrouping<object, BookLevels> booklevel, int index = 0)
    {
        root.ChildGroups[index] = new PivotGroup(
        new PivotGroupKey("Book Level " + (index + 3).ToString(), booklevel.Key.ToString()),
        new PivotRow(null, new string[8]),
        AddChildren(root, booklevel[index], index + 1), false, 0);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] paths = new string[] {
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!15712",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!15722",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!13891",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!DDD!15712",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!DDD!15722",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!DDD!13891",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!BBB!DDD!15812",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!BBB!DDD!15822",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!BBB!DDD!13891",
        };

        BuildTree(paths);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I think my issue might be the way I am creating the Linq statement that breaks up the string, since I'm not sure how to progress thru it recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what goes into which property. Also, for sake of simplicity and to be able to concentrate on the recursive algorithm, I redefine the group class like this (it does not mean that you have to change your class, instead, adapt my algorithm):

```
public class PivotGroup
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<PivotGroup> ChildGroups { get; } = new List<PivotGroup>();
    public override string ToString() => Key; // Makes debugging easier.
}
```

The idea is that the values of the path go into the key. I made `ChildGroups` a list to be able to add children successively. My `BuildTree` returns the root

```
static PivotGroup BuildTree(string[] paths)
{
    var root = new PivotGroup { Key = "ROOT" };
    foreach (string path in paths) {
        AddChildren(root, path.Split('!').Skip(1).ToList());
    }
    return root;
}
```

The recursive part goes into `AddChildren`. I convert the path into a `List<string>` to be able to remove the added part. `AddChildren` assumes that the first item in `path` is the first child to be added.

```
static void AddChildren(PivotGroup group, List<string> path)
{
    string key = path[0];
    int index = group.ChildGroups.FindIndex(g => g.Key == key);
    PivotGroup child;
    if (index >= 0) { // A child with this key exists.
        child = group.ChildGroups[index]; // Select this existing child.
    } else { // This key is missing. Add a new child.
        child = new PivotGroup { Key = key };
        group.ChildGroups.Add(child);
    }
    if (path.Count > 1) {
        path.RemoveAt(0); // Remove the added child key and add the rest recursively.
        AddChildren(child, path);
    }
}
```

We add children by walking down the tree and adding new children if necessary.

This prints the tree recursively:

```
private static void PrintTree(PivotGroup group, int level)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', 2 * level) + group.Key);
    foreach (PivotGroup child in group.ChildGroups) {
        PrintTree(child, level + 1);
    }
}
```

```
string[] paths = new string[] {
    "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!15712",
    ...
};

PivotGroup root = BuildTree(paths);
PrintTree(root, 0);
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

We could also use a loop instead of doing a recursion, since we add one branch at a time:

```
static PivotGroup BuildTree(string[] paths)
{
    var root = new PivotGroup { Key = "ROOT" };
    foreach (string path in paths) {
        PivotGroup group = root;
        string[] pathElements = path.Split('!');
        for (int i = 1; i < pathElements.Length; i++) { // Element [0] is ROOT, we skip it.
            string key = pathElements[i];
            int index = group.ChildGroups.FindIndex(g => g.Key == key);
            PivotGroup child;
            if (index >= 0) { // A child with this key exists.
                child = group.ChildGroups[index]; // Select this existing child.
            } else { // This key is missing. Add a new child.
                child = new PivotGroup { Key = key };
                group.ChildGroups.Add(child);
            }
            group = child;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

`List<T>.FindIndex` is inefficient for large lists. If you have large data sets and the order does not matter, switch to `Dictionary<string, PivotGroup>`. If you need the data to be sorted, use `SortedDictionary<string, PivotGroup>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple recursive code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string[] paths = new string[] {
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!15712",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!15722",
            "ROOT!ZZZ!AAA!EEE!13891"};

            List<List<string>> inputData = paths.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] {'!'}).ToList()).ToList();

            Node root = new Node();
            Node.ParseTree(root, inputData);
        }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Node> children { get; set; }

        public static void ParseTree(Node parent, List<List<string>> inputData)
        {
            parent.name = inputData.First().FirstOrDefault();
            var groups = inputData.Select(x => x.Skip(1)).GroupBy(x => x.Take(1).FirstOrDefault());
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                if (group.Key != null)
                {
                    if (parent.children == null) parent.children = new List<Node>();
                    Node newNode = new Node();
                    parent.children.Add(newNode);
                    ParseTree(newNode, group.Select(x => x.Select(y => y).ToList()).ToList());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```